# Statistics List in Tigase Component

Tags: xmpp, tigase

In my Tigase component i have override getStatistics method to add the statistics ( i.e. no of spam messages, all process packets etc) in the list. How can i access that list outside that method or component.In this [Component implementation - Lesson 5 - Statistics](http://www.tigase.org/content/component-implementation-lesson-5-statistics) its written that 
**"All the server statistics are exposed and are accessible via XMPP with ad-hoc commands, HTTP, JMX and some selected statistics are also available via SNMP"**  so is there any command which let me to get all the statistics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to gather Tigase statistics:

1. Admin Ad-hoc command via XMPP. You have to connect from through an admin account to the Tigase server, browse service discovery and then execute command on the Statistics provider component. I recumbent Psi client for this.
2. Another way is to connect via JMX protocol using JConsole or similar application. Then you can collect all the Java statistics plus, the Tigase provides own bean to browse it's statistics or just download them all (it might be 1,000 or more metrics from the server).
3. Also through JMX but might be more convenient using our utility class: JavaJMXProxyOpt. You can write a very simple command line tool which collects Tigase statistics and dumps it to a text file. The class offers a few options for a periodic statistics download, etc....

Comment: thank
Can you please tell me how to run bash scripts inside **bash** directory. Any link where i can get better understanding